# How else can l'inversion be used in French, other than to ask questions?

Tags: inversion, incises

I was reading this article from Le Monde and I don't understand how this sentence makes sense:

> "...dans le cadre de l’enquête en cours sur l’attentat du jeudi 14
>   juillet à Nice, a-t-on appris de source judiciaire."

How does the last part of the sentence make sense? Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

This inversion is compulsory in an interpolated clause indicating who expresses speech or thought in direct or indirect speech. This sort of clause is either placed between commas or at the end of the sentence after a comma.

Direct speech :

> « Il va faire chaud aujourd'hui », dit Pierre.
>   « Il va faire chaud aujourd'hui », dit-il.

Indirect speech :

> Il va faire chaud aujourd'hui, dit Pierre en prenant sa casquette.

- > [...] a-t-on appris de source judiciaire.

  is equivalent to indirect speech, if we've learned it, it is because someone said it. We could have :

  > [...] nous a-t-on dit de source judiciaire.

Il s'agit ici d'une inversion obligatoire dans une proposition incise  utilisée pour rapporter les propos de quelqu'un.

Comment: Your last sentence is in french ;)

Comment: @Loïc C'est la version française abrégée de ce qui est dit au-dessus. Les gens qui viennent ici le font surtout pour apprendre le français, c'est le moins qu'on leur doit. It's  the main idea (without examples) of what is being said in English just above. Most visitors  come to FL to learn some French and when time permitting I do a version in both French & English, I feel it's the least I owe them.

Comment: @Random: Gonna leave this last one I think... does it look so weird to have both?

Comment: Oui ça se comprend, après comme la question est en anglais et que la réponse est principalement anglaise, c'est étrange la dernière phrase en français, je pensais que tu t'étais emmêlée ^^

Comment: @Loic Pour citer *Le nom de la rose* en défense de ma camarade, je dirais que Laure **ist ein good catholico**. Give her a break ;-)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the *incise* already answered by Laure, there are other cases where inversion must or can be done in French:

- Perhaps he doesn't like chocolate:

  > - *Peut-être n'aime-t-il pas le chocolat*
  > - *<s>Peut-être il n'aime pas le chocolat</s>*
  > - *Peut-être qu'il n'aime pas le chocolat*

Sometimes, both orders are valid:

- I don't get what that question means :

  > - *Je ne comprends pas ce que signifie cette question.*
  > - *Je ne comprends pas ce que cette question signifie.*
- He let the prisoner flee:

  > - *Il a laissé s'échapper le prisonnier.*
  > - *Il a laissé le prisonnier s'échapper.*
- Taste the cake your mother prepared.

  > - *Goûte le gateau qu'a fait ta mère.*
  > - *Goûte le gateau que ta mère a fait.*

Answer (score 1):

This is affirmative (.), rather than interrogative (?):

- a-t-on appris que ? (Did learn that/if?)
- (), a-t-on appris récemment. (..., so we learnt recently)

Such a figure of speech, when handled carefully, with the correct intonation, may express different shades. First, it may sound more literary, yet more or less neutral as in your example. But it can express surprise, amusement, especially when you are face-to-face which the person you have just learnt something about.

> Tu apprends le français, m'a-t-on dit...

Generally, such a sentence indirectly asks for an answer, as if it was a question.